# How can I combine regex with a string?

Tags: c#, regex

I am fairly new to using regex and I am not entirely clear on the syntax for everything yet. Basically I am stuck on a bit of code where I have:

```
if(@"\d{2,}\s"+string == Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dir)) 
{ 
    do stuff 
}
```

My problem is that it won't match anything. I basically have a bunch of files that it's searching through that all have 2 digits and a space, then the name that the user is searching for. Can I combine regex + string like that or is the problem with my regex/statement?  Just for clarity, it will match when I actually remove the two digits and space from the files. I apologize if the problem is obvious, I've only been playing with regex for a few days...

Comment: That's definitely not correct C# syntax.

Comment: String == doesn't have anything to do with regexes.  It will just do a literal text compare.  You need to use Regex.IsMatch or Regex.Matches to compare a string with a regex, not ==

Comment: No. If that *were* valid syntactically (which it isn't), that does nothing to evaluate the regular expression. It would simply concatenate `\d{2,}\s` and the content of `string` into a single string - what you call a "regex" would be simply a literal string. Instead of trying to hack a regex into things (which isn't always appropriate), why not explain what you're trying to accomplish and ask how to to so?

Comment: If you want a string to be considered as a part of a regular expression, strings can be matched as literals within the regex. Example: `\d{3}pie` will match any three digits and the word pie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `if` statement is not attempting to match a regular expression pattern, it's simply comparing two strings. That's what the [`Regex.IsMatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is for. Also you will probably want to use [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to combine a regex pattern with an arbitrary string.

Try this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

var pattern = @"\d{2,}\s" + Regex.Escape(myString);
var fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(dir);
if (Regex.IsMatch(fileName, pattern))
{ 
    // do stuff 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually shouldn't have to use a Regular Expression in that instance, in fact that may be over complicating the goal.

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
string [] file = Directory.GetFiles(path, @"11_*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
foreach(string f in file)
{
    // Do Something.
}
```

If your entirely headset on utilizing Regular Expressions, you would do something more along these lines:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

    string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
    var file = Regex.IsMatch(path, @"\d{2,}\2");
    if(file == true)
    {
         // Do Something
    }
```

That is one way to use Regular Expressions, they can be even more powerful with `Linq`. I would highly recommend researching this on the MSDN, it has some solid resources.